# if statement for meta language tag on multi-language site

Tags: language, if, meta

Going through some SEO lists and found that magento websites do not provide the proper meta language information in the head on all pages.

Very simple to correct on uni-lingual websites, modify the **head.phtml** file located in **/app/design/frontend/default/YOUR_THEME/template/page/html/**

In the meta section add the following (replace *en-CA* with the correct language of your store):

```
<meta name="language" content="en-CA" />
```

To address the issue on a multiluange site I've composed the following code:

```
<div class="meta-language">

    <?php if($getStreId ==1) :?>
 <meta name="language" content="en-CA" /> 
        <?php endif; ?>
<meta name="language" content="fr-CA" /> 
            </div>
```

The site id 1 is for Enlish, the other will be French (2 languages).

When I inspect the code with *Firebug* I see the following:

```
<meta name="language" content="en-CA" />
<meta name="language" content="fr-CA" />
```

The expected result was to only see the active language for the meta language tag.

**How can the code be modified to only show the active language ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if` statement should also have an `else`, so it would be something like this

```
<div class="meta-language">
<?php if($getStreId ==1) :?>
   <meta name="language" content="en-CA" /> 
<?php else:    
   <meta name="language" content="fr-CA" /> 
<?php endif;?>
</div>
```

however there shouldn't be a `<div>` in the `<head>` section of your HTML. So you might want to drop that.

Also, there's not really a need to edit the `head.phtml` to add the `<meta>` tag. You can add the following to your `local.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <STORE_encastorecode>
       <default>
          <reference name="head">
              <block type="core/text" name="meta_language">
                 <action method="setText"><text><meta name="language" content="en-CA" /> </text></action>
              </block>
          </reference>
       </default>
    </STORE_encastorecode>
    <STORE_frcastorecode>
       <default>
          <reference name="head">
              <block type="core/text" name="meta_language">
                 <action method="setText"><text><meta name="language" content="fr-CA" /> </text></action>
              </block>
          </reference>
       </default>
    </STORE_frcastorecode>
</layout>
```

Just make sure you add the right storeview code to the `<STORE>` tag